# Как запретить чтение файлов по прямой ссылке в http.server?

Tags: python

Мой сайт, написанный на cgi, берет данные из обычного текстовика. Проблема в том, что при переходе по прямой ссылке на файл python я вижу значение файлов. Как мне избежать этого?

```
import http.server as BaseHTTPServer
import http.server as CGIHTTPServer
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()  
server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
handler = CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler
server_address = ("", 8000)
handler.cgi_directories = ["/cgi-bin"]
httpd = server(server_address, handler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Что такое значения файлов? Какое отношение имеет cgi к доступу к файлам? Непонятно ничего

Comment: Я читаю файлы и беру из них данные для сайта

Comment: Окей, и что мешает читать файлы в python?

Comment: Перейти по ссылке 192.AA.A.A/ФАЙЛ.txt

Comment: Переходите на здоровье, а при чём тут cgi и python? Всё ещё ничего не понятно

Comment: Мне не надо, Чтобы кто-то переходил и видел файлы. Я описал все в вопросе, читайте внимательнее.

Comment: Просто отключите раздачу файлов в настройках вашего веб-сервера. Это по-прежнему не имеет никакого отношения ни к cgi, ни к python

Comment: Как это настроить кодом? Мой сервер https://repl.it/repls/AbandonedDramaticBackticks

Comment: Вот теперь уже становится немного понятнее, перенесите этот код и ваши пояснения из комментариев в текст вопроса (без ссылок)

Comment: Пояснения-то тоже в вопрос перенесите. Без комментариев непонятно, чем вас не устраивает этот код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте свой собственный handler с прописанным внутри запретом на чтение не-cgi файлов:

```
from http import HTTPStatus
from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()


class CustomHTTPRequestHandler(CGIHTTPRequestHandler):
    cgi_directories = ["/cgi-bin"]

    def send_head(self):
        if not self.is_cgi():
            self.send_error(HTTPStatus.FORBIDDEN, "Access denied")
            return None
        return super().send_head()


server_address = ("", 8000)
httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, CustomHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

---

И имейте в виду, что

> **Warning:** http.server is not recommended for production. It only implements basic security checks.